# In Wagtail, get counts of Pages in each Tag, but only counting live() Pages

Tags: wagtail

In [Wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/) I want to get a list of Tags, each with a count of the number of Pages tagged, but only counting `live()` pages.

Let's say I have this set-up, [from the docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#custom-tag-models):

```py
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from taggit.models import TagBase, ItemBase

class BlogTag(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "blog tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "blog tags"


class TaggedBlog(ItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        BlogTag, related_name="tagged_blogs", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        to='demo.BlogPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tagged_items'
    )

class BlogPage(Page):
    ...
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through='demo.TaggedBlog', blank=True)
```

I can get a list of `BlogTag`s, each with a `count` of the number of `BlogPage`s tagged with it, by doing this (I *think* that's what it's doing...?):

```py
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

BlogTag.objects.annotate(count=Count("tagged_blogs"))
```

But I can't get my head round how to filter this to only count pages that are `live()` (or that have some other Page-related quality).

Answer (score 0):

I think this two-stage process works. First get all the Page IDs filtered by whatever you need, like `live()`. Then filter the `BlogTag`s by those

```py
page_ids = Page.objects.live().values_list("id", flat=True)

BlogTag.objects.filter(
    tagged_blogs__content_object_id__in=page_ids
).annotate(count=Count("tagged_blogs"))
```

I thought I'd have to filter the second query to only get `BlogTag`s with a `count` greater than 0 but it doesn't include tags with no pages anyway.

I don't know if this is the best solution, given it starts with having to get a list of *all* live pages, so maybe there's a better solution?